# Addressing objects and arrays nested in an object?

Tags: 7, views, entities, theming

I'm working a .tpl file for my view that is named `views-view-fields--viewname--block.tpl.php`. With the Devel module, I did a `dsm($field);` One of the field objects that are returned in the Krumo goes as follows:

```
fieldObject  
    --handler(object)  
    ----last_tokens(array)  
    ------[title](string, 15characters)
```

I figured I should address this as

```
    <?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php dsm($field); ?>
    <?php if ($field->class == 'field-evenement-performer'){
        print $field->handler->last_tokens['title'];    } 

?>
```

but this returns `Notice: Undefined index: title in include() (line 34 of /....../sites/all/themes/ibrain092012/templates/views-view-fields--presentatie-kraakhuis--block.tpl.php`

How can this be while title does have a value in the Krumo?

Comment: You're debugging `$fields` but accessing `$field` (no 's') could that be it?

Comment: `$field` should be right since it's in the loop as I now added to the code in my question

Comment: I didn't read your comment properly. You're right. The Krumo I described in the question, is still the one that is generated from `dsm($field);` as it is in my real code. So actually the `dsm($field);` - without the 's' was in my code the whole time, but copied it in my question the wrong way (twice!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to use it (see the usage of the square brackets in the string):

```
print $field->handler->last_tokens['[title]'];
```